# SCALA: error: value id is not a member of type parameter T

Tags: scala

In my quest to expand my knowledge on Scala, I see some things that seem not possible due to generics constraints - gleaned from another question.

I have a contrived example. This works:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
case class Z (a1:String, b1:String, id: Integer)
var d = new ArrayBuffer[Z]()  // empty buffer is created
d = ArrayBuffer(Z("Mark", "Hamlin", 2), Z("Kumar", "XYZ", 3), Z("Tom", "Poolsoft", 4)) 
for (x <- d) {
  val s = x.id
  println(s)  
}
```

Assume I have some common processing using generics - this does *not* work:

```
def someDef[T](x: ArrayBuffer[T]): Unit = { 
    for (a <- x) {
         println("hello...")
         val s = a.id  // without this it works
         println(s)    // println(a) works         
        }
} 

someDef(d)
```

Get this as error:

```
command-1621988840751517:18: error: value id is not a member of type parameter T
         val s = a.id
                   ^
```

What is the work around if this to be used for a set of classes represented by T in which we want part of the T to be accessed? I.e. generic processing - on those real generic aspects. `val s = a.id` or some filtering? Seems restrictive. I get that there is a restriction, but how does one code around this?

Comment: You want polymorphism: https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4 - another approach is to ask for the different logic, like `def someDef[T, I](x: ArrayBuffer[T])(getId: T => I): Unit = {`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  can I ask you to post answers pls in future! Good stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, you can have a `T` that does not have an `id`, such as `someDef(new ArrayBuffer[Int]())`, so it is not type sound, that is why the type checker does not compile it. `T` needs to be constrained by making `Z` the *upper bound* of `T`. Now `T` always has `id`:

```
  def someDef[T <: Z](x: ArrayBuffer[T]): Unit = // ...
```

EDIT: If you want the `id` value from `T` and `Z` was just an example, you can achieve that with an advanced type of polymorphism called *[structural types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Structural_Typing)* or colloquially known as *[duck typing](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-duck-typing-in-scala-structural-types/)*. I'll let you read about it, and show you that in action:

```
  def someDef[T <: { val id: Integer }](x: ArrayBuffer[T]): Unit = // ...
```

Now `T` can be any type (subtype of `AnyRef`), as long as it has a `val id: Integer` defined:

```
case class Z(a1: String, b1: String, id: Integer)
val d = ArrayBuffer(Z("Mark", "Hamlin", 2), Z("Kumar", "XYZ", 3), Z("Tom", "Poolsoft", 4))

someDef(d)

case class A(whatever: String, id: Integer)
val d2 = ArrayBuffer(A("We", 1), A("are", 2), A("the", 3), A("champions", 4))

someDef(d2)
```

**Note** this technique uses *reflection*, so you may to avoid it, when performance is a concern.

Comment: I have the impression I am asking something quite simple. I really have to look at this.  Looks impressive.

Comment: No, all classes will have the same id as an attribute. I edited the post as I had a wrong attribute name in class. I am just wanting to see if you can have a generic def with different classes to see if a common attribute can be accessed (for filtering). From yesterday's answer, I just want to see how advanced we can get. Seems difficult. This statement you made is what I mean: Since T has no bounds, you want some id, defined on T for any type T, meaning defined on Any.  But id will be a common attribute / field.

Comment: I am not sure a subtype, just any class of a set of classes that all have id as an attribute.

Comment: New aspect for me. See if I can call it.

Comment: This work for class Z, but as soon as I have a class A, for example, then this approach does not work. I want it to be generic if it can.

Comment: I think it is not possible now, due to your comment on generics the other day.

Comment: I finally understood what you want. And  yes, this can be achieved. I reedited my answer.

Comment: Sorry then for the poor explanation, but great stuff.

Comment: Transgressing from Spark scala to scala pure is no mean thing. At least that is how I see it.